# What level of detail can Google Analytics give me?

Tags: google-analytics

We are about to send out invitations to our website to a select number of people.

Using Google Analytics, I'd like to know if someone in Macon, GA (for example) has visited our website.

Q: Is there a way to see a breakdown of the IP address or geographic location of each  visitor?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the documentation about [Location](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1144408?hl=en), they say :

> This report lets you see where traffic originate (Continent, Sub Continent, Country, City). For web traffic, Location is derived from
>   mapping IP addresses to geographic locations

From my personal experience, yes, i can see the map and check out the location of each visitors.

Answer (score 0):

In your GA reporting view, you can go to Audience > Geo > Location, and then select "City" as the Primary Dimension, or you can keep "Country" as the Primary Dimension and add "City" as the Secondary Dimension. You won't be able to break down each visitor by country/city, but instead they will be grouped together.

Hope this helps.